VLOOKUP in Google Sheets
I am following the directions in the following Google help article https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en but I cannot get past an error "VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range."
This is my formula =VLOOKUP(C8,Users!A3:A35,3,FALSE)
I am trying to use the value of one cell to find a match in another sheet in the workbook and then retrieve the corresponding value in the other sheet in a different column.
Sheet1 with VLOOKUP formula

This is the Users Sheet where I am trying to do the lookup and return the corresponding name



You may try:
=VLOOKUP(C8,Users!A3:C35,3,FALSE)

or to avoid confusion go with xlookup()
=XLOOKUP(C8,Users!A3:A35,Users!C3:C35,)

